# How do the various configuration files determine MANPATH on Darwin?

Tags: path, man, darwin

On Darwin (12.2.0, OS X 10.8.2, bash 3.2.48(1)) my MANPATH appears to be [determined by my PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63583/9297) rather than by the various configuration files associated with `man` and the `man` path, `/etc/manpaths`, `/etc/man.conf` and several files in `/etc/manpaths.d`. How do these files figure into the MANPATH building process?

Comment: `man manpath` might yield an answer.

Comment: @sampablokuper Oh, the answer is there. I didn't see it. Can you point it out?

Comment: I'm not using OS X 10.8.2, so `man manpath` is likely to show me something different to what it shows you. Sorry not to be able to help more.